# Missing helper ifEquals

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Couldnt figure out a way to make this error go away. I've tried messing around with the handlebars plugin but it wouldn't do the application any good either.

**Below is my main app.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')

var hbs = exphbs.create({});
hbs.handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(arg1, arg2, options) {
    return (arg1 == arg2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
});

const { formatDate, radioCheck } = require("./helpers/hbs");

// Handlebars Middleware
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ 
    helpers: {
        radioCheck: radioCheck,
        formatDate: formatDate,

      for: function (from, to, incr, block) {
        var accum = "";
        for (var i = from; i < to; i += incr) accum += block.fn(i);
        return accum;
      },
      sum: function (arr) {
        const ar = JSON.parse(arr);
        return ar.reduce((pVal, cVal) => parseInt(cVal) + parseInt(pVal));
      },
      json: function (content) {
        return JSON.stringify(content);
      },
    },

    defaultLayout: 'main',
    handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars) // Specify default template views/layout/main.handlebar
  })
);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

**Below here is where the helper is supposed to be called in the front end**

```
{{#if user}}
<li class="nav-item dropdown" style="margin-top: 0px;font-size:22px;font-weight:500;margin-right:5px;margin-left:10px;">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
        style="color: black;">
        <img border="0" alt="logo" src="/img/shoppingCart.png" width="50" height="50" style="margin-top: -25px;">
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="/video/listVideos" class="dropdown-item">Videos</a>
        <a href="/video/addVideo" class="dropdown-item">Add Video</a>
    </div>
</li>
{{#ifEquals user.role 'A'}}
<li class="nav-item dropdown" style="margin-top: 0px;font-size:22px;font-weight:500;margin-right:5px;margin-left:10px;">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
        style="color: black;">Admin</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="/product/addProduct" class="dropdown-item">Add Product</a>
        <a href="/product/showProduct" class="dropdown-item">All Products</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">All Orders</a>
        <a href="/showRevenue" class="dropdown-item">Revenue</a>
        <a href="/adminfaq" class="dropdown-item">Staff FAQ</a>
        <a href="/user/homeadmin" class="dropdown-item">All Users</a>
        <a href="/logout" class="dropdown-item">Logout</a>
    </div>
</li>
{{/ifEquals}}
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue and I am able to call the helper when it is registered globally as is done in your example. However, I am curious if, instead of using `registerHelper`, defining the `ifEquals` helper in the `helpers` config - along with `radioCheck`, `formatDate`, etc. - would work?

Comment: Tried your suggestion but still getting the same error once the app tries to use the helper

Comment: There may be something at play that is not apparent in the given code. Do the other helpers, like `radioCheck` and `formatDate` work or is `ifEquals` the only one that produces the error?

Comment: Yes the other helpers still work. I tried downgrading the Handlebars version and removed the lines for `allowInsecurePrototypeAccess` and it worked. Thanks for the help still.